# Performance tuning SparkSQL Query (with Anti Join)

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

I have been recently introduced to `Spark-SQL`. I have written a `Spark-SQL` query that is running for a long time and hence I need to tune it to limit its execution time within an acceptable range.

Firstly, the query uses an `Anti-Join` between the **source** table and the **target** table in order to discard any already existing key record in tableT and consider only the new key records from the source. Only records from src tableA needs to be picked up which are **NOT** already present in tableT.

Primarily, I am eager to find out if this query could be re-written to be reduce execution time.  Secondly, if the logic to pickup the new records from the source by joining to tableT could be re-written in a different way to be more efficient.

**tableA**(source):

```
id|name|Loc|cover_sk|dtid
10|John|CA|2346|3
20|Mark|MD|7459|5
30|Mike|MO|1345|6
40|Josh|CT|9898|2
```

**tableT** (current state after previous run)

```
id|name|loc|cover|day_of_week
20|Mark|MD|1234|5
40|Josh|CT|6789|6
```

**tableC**:

```
cover_sk|cover_key|start_date
2346|EXT|2018-03-23
7459|AMB|2019-12-31
1345|DFE|2015-05-06
9898|RTE|2017-09-23
6189|EXT|2014|01-01
```

**datedim** (date dimension):

```
dateid|day_of_week
2|2
3|3
5|5
6|6
8|1
9|2
```

Expected Output:

```
id|name|loc|cover|day_of_week
10|John|CA|1234|3
30|Mike|MO|6789|6
```

**Requirements**:

1. From src, pick the new records which are not present in tableT. In
   this case ids 20 & 40 are already present in tableT hence we pickup
   and proceed with the remaining records -ids i.e 10 & 30 from the
   source (tableA). Discard 20 & 40 from tableA since they are already
   present in tableT.
2. Join tableC with data selected in previous step to pick up
   cover_key. In this case 2346 & 1345 gets picked, because in Step 1
   we had picked up ids 10 & 30 and had ignored ids 20, 40 since it
   already existed in tableT
3. Finally join resultset from previous step to datedim to pick up
   day_of_week.

I have the following query:

```
SELECT
src.id, src.name, src.loc, c.cover_key, dt.day_of_week
FROM tableA src -- source table
LEFT ANTI JOIN tableT tgt -- Join with tableT to identify and discard existing keys
ON src.id = tgt.id
LEFT JOIN tableC c
ON src.cover_sk = c.cover_sk
INNER JOIN datedim dt
ON src.dateid = dt.dateid
```

The sizes of the tables are as as below:

```
tableA: 389,000,000 rec
tableT: 300,000,000 rec
tableC: 16,000 rec
datedim: 115 rec
```

The entire query is running for 2 hours straight and i think it has some ground for tuning.
Also, I have tried plain LEFT JOIN instead of LEFT **ANTI** JOIN, to do the record existence check (of records in tableT) but in vain.
Any help is appreciated.

Note: I only have access to `Spark-SQL` but **NOT** PySparkSQL

Thanks

Comment: Provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what the code should be doing.

Comment: @GordonLinoff thanks for replying. I have updated the question with sample examples and original table sizes

Answer (score 0):

I suggest doing a re-partition on the tableA and tableB using id column for both, as for the number of partitions, it depends on the number of executors/cores/memory used. Additionally, try to broadcast the tableC and datedim tables. Hope this Helps.

Comment: Thanks for your response...i only have access to write Spark-SQL (don't have access to PySpark). Can you please suggest how to use the re-partition in the sql query with an example ?

Comment: SELECT /*+ REPARTITION(3) */ * FROM t; from https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-syntax-qry-select-hints.html